# Is there a new "Read-More-auto-insert" feature active on the sites?

Tags: discussion, answers, hyperlinks

I started writing a new answer just now on Chem.SE, and all of a sudden I realized some text had appeared that I (am pretty sure I) hadn't typed:

[image: auto-"Read More" text screencap]

Is this some sort of new automagic thingummy? Is there any way to turn it off? Edit its template?

As it is, frankly, it's pretty unattractive. Totally ungrammatical. If this is going to be a permanent thing, at least can it be formatted correctly?

Something like:

> Read more: http://autolink.com

Or, maybe:

> To read more, see: http://autolink.com

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. That's added by a clipboard-hijacking script on the site you copied the text from.

It's pretty common. They want to make certain that people who copy their text and paste it elsewhere include a link back to the source, so they pad the copy text with a read more link, as you see there.

Not all sites do it but it's not something that Stack Exchange does (or could likely implement).

The simple solution is to just delete it and link to the source the way you wish to... but please, do link to the source.

Comment: Yep, looks like that's it. Obvious in retrospect, thanks.  And yes, I absolutely [linked the source](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/94986).

Comment: Wikipedia adds a "warn" filter for edits that add these texts in.

Comment: If someone knows a way to warn about this in Firefox, please post an answer at [*Warn me when I copy hidden content from a webpage*](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/11080/60) :)